# String Find Does Not Find Substring As Expected

Tags: c++, arrays

I am creating a code that lets the user choose what they'd like to perform from a menu. When I run my code I select choice 'E' and I enter the word I want to be searched. The result comes out that the word is not in the sentence even though it is. Any reason why ? Thank you in advance

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cctype>

using namespace std;
int main()
{

    string s;
    char selection;
    string w;

    cout << "Enter a paragraph or a sentence : " ;

    getline(cin, s);

    int sizeOfString = s.length(); 

    //cout << "The paragraph has " << sizeOfString << " characters. " << endl; ***Dummy call to see if size works. 

    //cout << "You entered " << s << endl; *** Dummy function !!

    cout << "" << endl;

    cout << "                 Menu          " << endl;
    cout <<"        ------------------------" << endl;
    cout << "" << endl;
    cout << "A -- Convert paragraph to all caps " << endl;
    cout << "B -- Convert paragraph to all lowercase " << endl;
    cout << "C -- Delete whitespaces " << endl;
    cout << "D -- Split words & remove duplicates " << endl;
    cout << "E -- Search a certain word " << endl;
    cout << "" << endl;
    cout << "Please select one of the above: " ;
    cin >> selection;
    cout << "" << endl;
    switch (selection) //Switch statement
    {
        case 'a':
        case 'A': cout << "You chose to convert the paragraph to all uppercase" << endl;
                  cout << "" << endl;
                  for(int i=0; s[i]!='\0'; i++)
                    {
                        s[i]=toupper(s[i]);
                    }
                    cout << "This is it: " << s << endl;
                  break;
        case 'b':
        case 'B': cout << "You chose to convert the paragragh to all lowercase" << endl;
                  cout << "" << endl;
                  for (int i=0; s[i] !='\0'; i++)
                  {
                      s[i]=tolower(s[i]);
                  }
                    cout << "This is it: " << s << endl;
                    break;
        case 'c':
        case 'C': cout << "You chose to delete the whitespaces in the paragraph" << endl;
                  cout << "" << endl;
                  for(int i=0; i<s.length(); i++)
                    if(s[i] == ' ') s.erase(i,1);
                  cout <<"This is it: " << s << endl;
                  break;
        case 'd':
        case 'D': cout << "You chose to split the words & remove the duplicates in the paragraph" << endl;
                  cout << "" << endl;

                  /*char arrayOne[] = s;
                    for (int i=0; i< s.length; i++)
                    {
                        cout << arrayOne[i] << endl;
                    }*/


        case 'e':
        case 'E': cout << "You chose to search for a certain word in the paragraph. " << endl;
                  cout << "" << endl;
                  cout << "Enter the word you want to search for: ";
                  cin >> w;

                  s.find(w);
                  if (s.find(w) == true)
                  {
                      cout << w << " was found in the paragraph. " << endl;

                  }
                  else if (s.find(w) != true);
                  {
                        cout << w << " was not found in the paragraph. " << endl;
                  }




    }


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In the future, please try to make your code samples minimal-but-complete to reduce the overhead/noise that other readers and potential answerers need to look at. For example, you could get rid of the other choices since 'E' is the only case that has issues. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: For example, you should be able to simplify all this code down to mainly line to debug: `if (s.find(w) == true)`. A sign of a decent programmer and debugger is the ability to isolate the area(s) where something is not behaving as desired, and logically work through the problem until you have found the faulty code and resolved it. A very valuable skill for any aspiring programmer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`std::string::find` returns the sub-string position, not a boolean. Check [the documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/).

if equal to `std::string::npos`, instance is not found, else, if (greater or equal to zero) it is found.

So:

```
if ( s.find( w ) )
```

Should be:

```
if ( s.find( w ) != std::string::npos )
```

And, by the way:

```
s.find(w);
if (s.find(w) == true)
{
    cout << w << " was found in the paragraph. " << endl;
}
else if (s.find(w) != true);
{
    cout << w << " was not found in the paragraph. " << endl;
}
```

Should be:

```
if ( s.find( w ) != std::string::npos )
    cout << w << " was found in the paragraph. " << endl;
else // no need to test again!
    cout << w << " was not found in the paragraph. " << endl;
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I have another question.  When the 4th choice (“Split Words”) is selected, the words should be put into an array or a structure and each word should be displayed with a loop. After this, duplicate removal should be performed and the program must determine the duplicate words and eliminate them. After this, the word list should be printed again. Would you happen to know how that works?

Comment: That's a different question, you should post a diffrent question or try to do it yourself using a `std::vector` or `std::set` (this one does not allow duplicates) to store and manipulate the words. If the issue presented here is fixed, please vote up and accept an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is with

```
if (s.find(w) == true)
```

[`find()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) returns the position of the found string not true or false.  If you want to check if it finds the word use

```
if (s.find(w) != std::string::npos)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I have another question.  When the 4th choice (“Split Words”) is selected, the words should be put into an array or a structure and each word should be displayed with a loop. After this, duplicate removal should be performed and the program must determine the duplicate words and eliminate them. After this, the word list should be printed again. Would you happen to know how that works

Comment: If you have another question you should [ask another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)

Answer (score 0):

I want to suggest the following to simplify your development / test effort:

```
bool DEVELOPEMENT_MODE = true;


int t247(void)
{
   std::string s;
   char selection;
   std::string w;

   std::cout << "Enter a paragraph or a sentence : " ;

   // instead of ONLY run-time fetch of paragraph or sentence
   if(DEVELOPEMENT_MODE)
   {
      // for developement use:
      std::stringstream ss;

      // TEST STRING
      ss << "the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog";

      s = ss.str();  // fill in test input

      size_t sizeOfString = s.length();        // note: not int

      // ***Dummy unit test to see if size works.
      std::cout << "The paragraph has " << sizeOfString 
                << " characters. " << std::endl; 

      // ***Dummy unit test
      std::cout << "You entered " << s 
                << std::endl;          
   }
   else
   {
      // for final test use run time entry of sentence
      getline(std::cin, s);
   }

   //...
```

---

As you get each function working, add more complexity to the test string (using the editor you normally use).

---

I often use argc or argv[1] (of main) to select which test to run.

---

Update:

By the way, you will find it difficult to read a paragraph using getline() without a loop.

However, the DEVELOPMENT_MODE code (with stringstream) can trivially create a paragraph.

```
 ss << "the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog";
```

can be easily expanded ... c++ auto-magically concatenates lines into a single line:

```
 ss << "the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog"
       "quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog the"
       "brown fox jumped over the lazy dog the brown";
```

But the above is not yet a paragraph.

The following is a 3 line paragraph:

```
 ss << "the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog\n"
       "quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog the\n"
       "brown fox jumped over the lazy dog the brown\n";
```